# How to set config value from Session var in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, configuration

Laravel version: 7.6.

I tried to set config dynamically.

In `AppServiceProvider.php`, I put like this.

```
 public function boot()
 {
   \Config::set("variable.custom", "test"); // this worked well.
 }
```

But I needed to get value from Session var.

```
public function boot()
{
  \Session::get("test"); // returned null even used Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session.
}
```

So I searched about it and found one answer.

```
public function boot()
{
   view()->composer('*', function () {
      $test= \Session::get("test");   // this worked well.
      \Config::set("variable.custom", $test); // but this didn't work.
   }

}
```

Is there any solution? Can anyone help me?

### Here is exact process.

First of all, I set `middleware` for checking `domain_id` session var.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        \URL::defaults([
            'domain' => $request->route()->parameter('domain'),
        ]);
        $domain = $request->route()->parameter('domain');

        if(!Session::has('domain_id')){
            $domain = Domain::where('domain', $domain)->firstorfail();

            Session::put('domain_id', $domain->id);
        };
        $request->route()->forgetParameter('domain');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In `AppServiceProvider.php` `boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{
  $dir = ['/storage/'.\Session::get("domain_id")?? 0];
  \Config::set("elfinder.dir", $dir);
}
```

I was going to set `elfinder.dir` dynamically according to domain.

Comment: Session and config are 2 different things. If you set in Config, I wonder how can you get it automatically in Session?

Comment: Where are you setting a value of `test` in the session?

Comment: It's value from subdomain. And from that subdomain, I will get another value from database.
I set that another value in session var.

Comment: In middleware, I get `subdomain` parameter. And from that `subdomain` parameter, I will get  `domain_id`  in database, And then I set `domain_id` in `session var`.

Comment: it would be much better if you add that code to the post